# Throwing Exception inside of Future's flatMap?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala>  Future(5).flatMap(_ => throw new Exception("!") )
res9: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> res9.value
res10: Option[scala.util.Try[Nothing]] = Some(Failure(java.lang.Exception: !))
```

Why does throwing an exception inside of `Future#flatMap` return a failed future?

Given its [signature](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future):

```
def flatMap[S](f: (T) ⇒ Future[S])
              (implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```

How does `_ => throw ...` return a `Future`?

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all `flatMap` maps the result of the receiving future, so it **returns instantly another future** (and therefore the exception is not immediately caught!). The function passed to `flatMap` takes the former future's result and must produce another future. Throwing an exception has type `Nothing` and that's a sub-type of any other type, satisfying `Nothing <: Future[A]` where `A` is inferred to be `Nothing` as well.

From the perspective of scala.concurrent, `flatMap(e => (throw new Exception()): Future[A])` and `flatMap(e => Future[A](throw new Exception())` must be treated the same, there is only one logical solution, return a failed future.

Comment: Can you please defend, `must be treated the same, there is only one logical solution, return a failed future.`? Why is a propagated exception **not** a logical result?

Comment: `x.flatMap[A](fun: B => Future[A]): Future[A]` cannot apply `fun` before `x` has completed. It must therefore return a value of type `Future[A]`, i.e. it can only do so by creating an internal `Promise[A]`. When `x` is ready, it must complete that future, otherwise you break the contract and leave the system in limbo. It must thus guard the application of `fun` itself against exceptions. __That *is* propagating the exception__

Comment: @KevinMeredith https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L246-L258  Note the try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

`throw` returns a "bottom type" `Nothing` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.Nothing which is a subtype of every other type. So throwing an exception inside a Future gets caught and a Future.failed is returned.

> Why does throwing an exception inside of Future#flatMap return a
>   failed future?

Because that's how it's supposed to work? What else would you expect?

Comment: It's not clear to me why the exception is caught, rather than propagating outside of the `Future`.

Comment: The answer lies in "What is on the outside?" Hint: ExecutionContext

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what @Falmarri said, IMHO throwing an exception inside a Future returns a failed Future (and this is the way I expect to work by the way) simply because the exceptions are being catch (old school java try catch)

Considering Scala 2.12

When you create a Future using the `apply` method (`Future { }` is syntactic sugar for `Future.apply`), you are actually [mapping a successful Future](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/21d12e9f5ec1ffe023f509848911476c1552d06f/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L652).

```
val unit: Future[Unit] = successful(())

def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = unit.map(_ => body)
```

A [map](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/21d12e9f5ec1ffe023f509848911476c1552d06f/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L287) is a call to `transform`

```
def map[S](f: T => S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = transform(_ map f)
```

The [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/21d12e9f5ec1ffe023f509848911476c1552d06f/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L27) of `transform` in `DefaultPromise` makes a try catch for NonFatal exceptions

```
  override def transform[S](f: Try[T] => Try[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    val p = new DefaultPromise[S]()
    onComplete { result => p.complete(try f(result) catch { case NonFatal(t) => Failure(t) }) } // Here is the magic
    p.future
  }
```

You can try it adding a breakpoint in the onComplete line, and then do

```
Future { throw new Exception("!") } // or Future.apply(throw new Exception("!")) or Future.unit.map(_ => throw new Exception("!"))
```

The `try f(result)` will be calling the map function of Success passing it your function (because the value of `Future.unit` is a `Success(())` ), because your function throws an exception it will be catch by `catch { case NonFatal(t) => Failure(t) }`

Something similar happens for the `flatMap`, but in this case it [calls](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/21d12e9f5ec1ffe023f509848911476c1552d06f/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L301) `transformWith`

```
  def flatMap[S](f: T => Future[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = transformWith {
    case Success(s) => f(s)
    case Failure(_) => this.asInstanceOf[Future[S]]
}
```

The `transformWith` [also does](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/21d12e9f5ec1ffe023f509848911476c1552d06f/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L34) a try catch

```
  override def transformWith[S](f: Try[T] => Future[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    val p = new DefaultPromise[S]()
    onComplete {
      v => try f(v) match {
        case fut if fut eq this => p complete v.asInstanceOf[Try[S]]
        case dp: DefaultPromise[_] => dp.asInstanceOf[DefaultPromise[S]].linkRootOf(p)
        case fut => p completeWith fut
      } catch { case NonFatal(t) => p failure t } // Here is the magic
    }
    p.future
}
```

However I'm not an scala expert, just did some debugging, so don't take what I said for granted.

Comment: Bonus: An [issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10616) about when an exception is not being captured and the Future never completes. Is an edge case